# MongoDb update multiple objects from array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a document with the following fields:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "codes": [
    {"name": "code1", "active": null, "disabled": false},
    {"name": "code2", "active": null, "disabled": false},
    {"name": "code3", "active": null, "disabled": false},
    {"name": "code4", "active": null, "disabled": false},
    {"name": "code5", "active": null, "disabled": false},
    {"name": "code6", "active": null, "disabled": false}
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to update just the objects that have the `name` value equal to "code2", "code3" and "code4"?

For example:

```
db.collection.update(
  {"_id": 1},
  {
    $set: {
      "codes": [
        {"name": "code2", "active": false, "disabled": true},
        {"name": "code3", "active": true, "disabled": false},
        {"name": "code4", "active": null, "disabled": true}
      ]
    }
  }
)
```

Expected result:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "codes": [
    {"name": "code1", "active": null, "disabled": false},
    {"name": "code2", "active": false, "disabled": true},
    {"name": "code3", "active": true, "disabled": false},
    {"name": "code4", "active": null, "disabled": true},
    {"name": "code5", "active": null, "disabled": false},
    {"name": "code6", "active": null, "disabled": false}
  ]
}
```

Actual result:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "codes": [
    {"name": "code2", "active": false, "disabled": true},
    {"name": "code3", "active": true, "disabled": false},
    {"name": "code4", "active": null, "disabled": true}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this in one query, however you can loop on your array of updates, and perform updates for element matching condition in codes array :

```
var updatesArray = [
    {"name": "code2", "active": false, "disabled": true},
    {"name": "code3", "active": true, "disabled": false},
    {"name": "code4", "active": null, "disabled": true}
  ]

updatesArray.forEach(function(newCode){
  db.getCollection("collection").update(
    {_id:1},   
    {$set:{
      "codes.$[subcode].active":newCode.active,
      "codes.$[subcode].disabled":newCode.disabled}
    },   
    { multi: true,
       arrayFilters: [ { "subcode.name": newCode.name } ]
    }
  )
})
```

Comment: That would get really slow if there is a large number of elements that need to be updated

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to achieve

```
db.collection.update(  {
   "_id": 1,
   "codes.name":{$in:{"code2","code3","code4"}}
},{$set:{"codes.$.active":true}})
```

Comment: Using this would set `active` to `true` in all of those 3 objects, which does not meet the expected result because each of the updated objects have different values for the `active` and `disabled` properties.